# MethodInfo.Invoke TargetException

Tags: c#, xna, system.reflection, methodinfo

I've an Issue with System.Reflection, when I call MethodInfo.Invoke method it gaves me the TargetException exception that says: Object does not match with target, Here the code:

```
object[] parms = new object[] { path };

Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
Type gameType = null;

foreach (Assembly asm in assemblies)
{
    string asmName = asm.GetName().Name;

    if (asmName == "Tester")
    {
        gameType = asm.GetType("Tester.Main");
        break;
    }
}

var game = Convert.ChangeType(GameInstance, gameType);
Type delegateType = game.GetType().GetEvent("gameVideoLoader").EventHandlerType;

MethodInfo method = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
method.Invoke(game,  parms); // Here the exception
```

Any Idea?
PS: game object is correctly assigned so it's not null

Answer (score 2):

What Jon said.

Also, if you're trying to do some hacking (and not production-level code), here's some practical advice: take a look at the source code (or use a disassembler such as Reflector or dotPeek) and see how the event is invoked.

- If there's a *method* that invokes it, use Reflection to call that method
- Otherwise, if the event is using a compiler-generated field, use `Type.GetField` to retrieve the field (it would have the same name as the event) and then call `GetValue` to get the actual delegate

  - If the delegate type is public, cast the value and invoke

    `((MyDelegate)fieldValue)(arg1, arg2...)`
  - Otherwise, cast to `Delegate` and use the dynamic invoke method

    `((Delegate)fieldValue).DynamicInvoke(new object[] { arg1, arg2 })`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the *delegate's* `Invoke` method, but on a `Tester.Main` instance. That's just wrong - because the `Tester.Main` instance *isn't* an instance of the appropriate delegate.

If you're trying to actually raise the `gameVideoLoader` event, then that's a different matter... and something that you shouldn't be doing anyway. The purpose of events is to allow clients to subscribe and unsubscribe handlers - the object itself should be responsible for raising the event. You *may* be able to find an underlying field which is used to implement the event, get the value of that field and invoke the delegate - but I'd strongly advise against it. You're basically going against the design of events at this point.

Comment: I've done what You've just said, now I can invoke the method but there's a problem, he gaves me another error that I was trying to avoid with delegates:

<code>

public Video ShowVideo(string videoPath)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(videoPath != null, "Argument 'video' can't be null!");

            Video video = new Video(videoPath, false);
            video.Size = gameWindow.Size;
            video.Owner = videoBox;
            videoBox.Visible = true;
            video.Play();

            return video;
        }
</code>

Comment: @ThomasSquall: That's code, not an error. You haven't told us what *error* you get. But again, what you're trying to do violates the design of events, and I'd strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Sorry I'm at work and when I was writing the answer they (who works with me) as searched me for issues so I've close the laptop before finish the answer, I will try to write it again XD